# Decompress an NTFS Windows File System Using Ubuntu

Tags: ntfs, windows-xp, compression

My friend (on windows xp) recently compressed his entire C:/ drive and consequently, his laptop won't boot, he gets "BOOTMGR is compressed Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart". This happens every time! I can boot ubuntu from the usb so I was wondering if it was possible to fix this issue? Thanks in advance, ell.

EDIT: His laptop does not have a cd drive

Comment: I doubt you can fix this with Ubuntu. Not having a CD drive is another issue, but what OS does he use? If the message contains BOOTMGR it's cetainly not Windows XP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's Windows XP and the NTLDR is compressed, then maybe this will work:

1. Install 'ntfsprogs'
2. Mount the Windows partition (eg. /dev/sda1):
   `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/winxp`
3. Copy the ntldr to your home dir (or somewhere else):
   `cp -p /mnt/winxp/ntldr ~`
4. Delete or backup the original ntldr file:
   `sudo mv /mnt/winxp/ntldr /mnt/winxp/ntldr.bak`
5. Copy the ntldr from your home folder back to the Windows partition using 'ntfscp' (this should uncompress it). You first need to unmount the partition:
   `sudo umount /mnt/winxp`
   then do:
   `ntfscp -v /dev/sda1 ~/ntldr ntldr`
6. To check if the operation was successful, you can run 'ntfsinfo':
   `sudo ntfsinfo -v -F /ntldr /dev/sda1`
   If this shows:
   `File attributes:    (0x00000000)`
   then the loader is fixed and you can try to boot (and I suggest you then untick the "Compress this Drive To Save Space" in C: properties).

Comment: Thanks, this set me on the right path, but there's some info missing. Step 5 didn't decompress the file, reading [ntfs-g3 docs](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/data-compression/) I found that it will compress the files again if the Folder is marked as Compressed (which is what caused the problem in the first place). Mounting /dev/sda1 and running this in the folder `setfattr -h -v 0x00000000 -n system.ntfs_attrib /mnt/windows` got rid of the flag. Then you can go ahead and copy the files. Also I needed to decompress a few more files because it happened with Windows7

Comment: You could also mount with `-o nocompression` and copy it back normally.

Answer (score 0):

[Tom Hale comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12331/decompress-an-ntfs-windows-file-system-using-ubuntu/1269174#comment1948025_12332) helped me, so I would like to create separate answer for this question.

Mounting FS with parameters `-o nocompression` helped me.